# What’s the difference between “sauce” and “gravy”?

Tags: differences, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spaghetti and gravy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/spaghetti-and-gravy)

For all translators I checked it means the same.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravy and Google

Comment: Short version: Gravy is a kind of sauce.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between sauce and dressing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60776/what-is-the-difference-between-sauce-and-dressing). That was closed as general reference, which means for consistency this ought to be closed, too; however, I think both questions hit on areas of language where inconsistencies and multiple incompatible meanings abound. (IOW, perhaps the older question ought to be reopened.)

Comment: Sauce is alcohol; gravy is money. They both help grease the wheels, hence the similarity.      ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that's asking about the (mis)use of "gravy" to mean "tomato sauce", which is a practice that's peculiar to a specific segment of Italian immigrants to the USA. While it's an interesting footnote, it's hardly definitive with regard to the *usual* uses of the words "sauce" and "gravy".

Comment: Gah! Ok, @Reg, explain how this is a duplicate. Please.

Comment: @Martha: you are absolutely welcome to edit the question into shape such that it builds on that other question or whatever. In its current form, it's a one-liner that *simply wouldn't exist* had Szczepan searched this site for *gravy*. Or looked it up in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravy).

Comment: @Martha: The answer in the dup [***I*** linked to](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2460/2637) cites *"gravy is a subset of sauces made from meat essence"*, which is all OP here needs to know.

Answer (score 4):

Per the OED, ***gravy*** is:

> The fat and juices which exude from flesh during and after the process of cooking; a dressing for meat or vegetables made from these with the addition of condiments.

Whereas ***sauce*** is:

> Any preparation, usually liquid or soft, and often consisting of several ingredients, intended to be eaten as an appetizing accompaniment to some article of food.

In other words, *sauce* is the more general of the two terms.  Furthermore, gravy is usually hot, whereas sauce can also be cold.

Finally, with the rise of vegetarian meal options, you now hear qualified versions like *mushroom gravy*, which is made of mushrooms **not** out of simmered flesh-juices, to be served hot over mashed potatoes and the like. In other words, to be used for the same thing as meat gravy is used, but not made from animal flesh.

Note also that while a raspberry sauce can be expected to be made of raspberries, that ***cranberry sauce*** is a relish made **from** cranberries, not something to be spread **atop** cranberries.  Things like ***Hollandaise sauce*** are something else again.

There are also extended, transferred, and metaphoric meanings of both these words, such ***gravy*** train, *stewing in one’s own **gravy***, and in the old proverb that what is ***sauce*** for the goose is **sauce** for the gander, as well as saying that someone has a ***saucy*** mouth, or that they have too much sauce meaning that they are impertinent. Sometimes, too, *sauce* can mean booze, at least in slang.

Comment: In Italian-American slang, *gravy* also means tomato sauce with spices served on pasta.

Comment: I think the OED definitions made the distinction rather well. Everything else here is just gravy ;^) On a more serious note, some culinarians will categorize sauces into one of the [basic 5 sauces](http://www.dvo.com/newsletter/monthly/2003/september/0903tabletalk4.html) (sometimes called the five ["mother sauces"](http://chefmilani.com/mothersauces.html)).